# Touchscreen Software Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen

I would like to get rid of all external components on my Pi so as to make it portable.  I have a GPIO attached touchscreen. Is there a software keyboard that I could use that:

- **Is fully functional** (has most of the keys on a standard keyboard)
- **Is customizable** (add or remove buttons to conform with users wants)
- Uses **QWERTY** layout

Is there a easy solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The [Matchbox Keyboard](https://github.com/xlab/matchbox-keyboard) can do exactly that! All you have to do is compile it. To customize it you can edit the `keyboard.xml` file found in `/usr/share/matchbox-keyboard/`. This [site](http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/Switching_Keyboards#Matchbox_keyboard) shows you how to install it. Each button can be removed, added, or customized. Here is an example of the `.xml` file listed above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<keyboard>
<options>
</options> 
<layout id="german keyboard">
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Esc" action="escape" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="^" />
        <shifted display="°" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="1" />
        <shifted display="!" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="2" />
        <shifted display='"' />
        <mod1    display="²" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="3" />
        <shifted display="§" />
        <mod1    display="³" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="4" />
        <shifted display="$" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="5" />
        <shifted display="%" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="6" />
        <shifted display="&amp;" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="7" />
        <shifted display="/" />
        <mod1    display="{" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="8" />
        <shifted display="(" />
        <mod1    display="[" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="9" />
        <shifted display=")" />
        <mod1    display="]" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="0" />
        <shifted display="=" />
        <mod1    display="}" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="?" />
        <shifted display="ß" />
        <mod1    display="\" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="'" />
        <shifted display="" />
  </key>
 <key fill="true">
       <default display="⌫" action="backspace"/>
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key width="4000"  extended="true">
        <default display="Home" action="home"/>
  </key>
  <key width="4000"  extended="true">
        <default display="PgUp" action="pageup"/>
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
</row>
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="↹" action="tab"/>
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="q" />
        <shifted display="Q" />
        <mod1    display="@" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="w" />
        <shifted display="W" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <mod1 display="€" />
        <default    display="e" />
        <shifted display="E" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="r" />
        <shifted display="R" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="t" />
        <shifted display="T" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="z" />
        <shifted display="Z" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="u" />
        <shifted display="U" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="i" />
        <shifted display="I" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="o" />
        <shifted display="O" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="p" />
        <shifted display="P" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="ü" />
        <shifted display="Ü" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="+" />
        <shifted display="*" />
        <mod1    display="~" />
  </key>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="◀┛" action="return"/>
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key width="4000"  extended="true">
       <default display="End" action="end"/>
  </key>
  <key width="4000"  extended="true">
        <default display="PgDn" action="pagedown"/>
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
</row>
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Caps" action="modifier:caps"/>
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="a" />
        <shifted display="A" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="s" />
        <shifted display="S" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="d" />
        <shifted display="D" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="f" />
        <shifted display="F" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="g" />
        <shifted display="G" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="h" />
        <shifted display="H" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="j" />
        <shifted display="J" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="k" />
        <shifted display="K" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="l" />
        <shifted display="L" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="ö" />
        <shifted display="Ö" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="ä" />
        <shifted display="Ä" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="#" />
        <shifted display="'" />
  </key>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="◀┛" action="return"/>
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <space width="4000"  extended="true" />
  <space width="4000"  extended="true" />
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
</row>
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Shift" action="modifier:shift"/>
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="&lt;" />
        <shifted display="&gt;" />
        <mod1    display="|" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="y" />
        <shifted display="Y" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="x" />
        <shifted display="X" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="c" />
        <shifted display="C" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="v" />
        <shifted display="V" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="b" />
        <shifted display="B" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="n" />
        <shifted display="N" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="m" />
        <shifted display="M" />
        <mod1 display="µ" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="," />
        <shifted display=";" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="." />
        <shifted display=":" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="-" />
        <shifted display="_" />
  </key>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Shift" action="modifier:shift"/>
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <space width="4000"  extended="true" />
  <space width="4000"  extended="true" />
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
</row>
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key fill="true">
       <default display="Strg" action="modifier:ctrl"/>
  </key>
  <key fill="true">
       <default display="[->]" action="modifier:layout"/>
  </key>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Alt" action="modifier:alt"/>
  </key>
  <key width="9500">
        <default display=" " action="space" />
  </key>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Alt Gr" action="modifier:mod1"/>
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="↑" action="up" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="↓" action="down" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="←" action="left" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="→" action="right" />
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <space width="4000"  extended="true" />
  <space width="4000"  extended="true" />
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
</row>
</layout>
<layout id="numpad keyboard">
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key>
        <default display="Num" action="modifier:caps" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="/" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="*" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="-" />
  </key>
  </row>
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="7" />
        <shifted display="Pos 1" action="home" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="8" />
        <shifted display="↑" action="up" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="9" />
        <shifted display="Bild ↑" action="pageup"/>
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="+" />
  </key>
  </row>
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="4" />
        <shifted display="←" action="left" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="5" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="6" />
        <shifted display="→" action="right"/>
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="+" />
  </key>
</row>
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="1" />
        <shifted display="Ende" action="end" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="2" />
        <shifted display="↓" action="down" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="3" />
        <shifted display="Bild ↓" action="pagedown"/>
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="◀┛" action="return" />
  </key>
</row>
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="0" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="," />
        <shifted display="Entf" action="delete"/>
  </key>
</row>
<row>
  <key>
        <default display="[->]" action="modifier:layout"/>
  </key>
</row>
</layout>
<layout id="default keyboard">
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Esc" action="escape" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="`" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="1" />
        <shifted display="!" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="2" />
        <shifted display='"' />
        <mod1    display="½" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="3" />
        <shifted display="£" />
        <mod1    display="¾" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="4" />
        <shifted display="$" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="5" />
        <shifted display="%" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="6" />
        <shifted display="^" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="7" />
        <shifted display="&" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="8" />
        <shifted display="*" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="9" />
        <shifted display="(" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="0" />
        <shifted display=")" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="-" />
        <shifted display="_" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="=" />
        <shifted display="+" />
  </key>
  <key fill="true">
       <default display="Bksp" action="backspace"/>
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key width="4000"  extended="true">
        <default display="Home" action="home"/>
  </key>
  <key width="4000"  extended="true">
        <default display="PgUp" action="pageup"/>
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
</row>
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Tab" action="tab"/>
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="q" />
        <shifted display="Q" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="w" />
        <shifted display="W" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <mod1 display="ë" />
        <default    display="e" />
        <shifted display="E" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="r" />
        <shifted display="R" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="t" />
        <shifted display="T" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="y" />
        <shifted display="Y" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="u" />
        <shifted display="U" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="i" />
        <shifted display="I" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="o" />
        <shifted display="O" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="p" />
        <shifted display="P" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="{" />
        <shifted display="[" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="}" />
        <shifted display="]" />
  </key>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="\" />
        <shifted display="|" />
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key width="4000"  extended="true">
        <default display="End" action="end"/>
  </key>
  <key width="4000"  extended="true">
        <default display="PgDn" action="pagedown"/>
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
</row>
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Caps" action="modifier:caps"/>
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="a" />
        <shifted display="A" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="s" />
        <shifted display="S" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="d" />
        <shifted display="D" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="f" />
        <shifted display="F" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="g" />
        <shifted display="G" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="h" />
        <shifted display="H" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="j" />
        <shifted display="J" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="k" />
        <shifted display="K" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="l" />
        <shifted display="L" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display=";" />
        <shifted display=":" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="#" />
        <shifted display="~" />
  </key>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Ret" action="return"/>
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <space width="4000"  extended="true" />
  <space width="4000"  extended="true" />
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
</row>
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Shift" action="modifier:shift"/>
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="z" />
        <shifted display="Z" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="x" />
        <shifted display="X" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="c" />
        <shifted display="C" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="v" />
        <shifted display="V" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="b" />
        <shifted display="B" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="n" />
        <shifted display="N" />
  </key>
  <key obey-caps='true'>
        <default display="m" />
        <shifted display="M" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="," />
        <shifted display="&lt;" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="." />
        <shifted display="&gt;" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="/" />
        <shifted display="?" />
  </key>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Shift" action="modifier:shift"/>
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <space width="4000"  extended="true" />
  <space width="4000"  extended="true" />
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
</row>
<row>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <key>
        <default display="[->]" action="modifier:layout"/>
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="äëö" action="modifier:mod1"/>
  </key>
  <key fill="true">
        <default display="Ctrl" action="modifier:ctrl"/>
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="Alt" action="modifier:alt"/>
  </key>
  <key width="12000">
        <default display=" " action="space" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="@" />
        <shifted display="'" />
  </key>
  <key>
       <default display="↑" action="up" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="↓" action="down" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="←" action="left" />
  </key>
  <key>
        <default display="→" action="right" />
  </key>
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
  <space width="4000"  extended="true" />
  <space width="4000"  extended="true" />
  <space width="500" extended="true"/>
</row>
</layout>
</keyboard>
```

You can even add a toggle button on the taskbar for easy access(see lower right hand corner of picture below). [Here is a complete guide](http://ozzmaker.com/2014/06/30/virtual-keyboard-for-the-raspberry-pi/) to setting it up.
[image]